# Payment method input boxes disabled by default - interesting Javascript incompatibility

Tags: javascript, forms, magento

This bit of code is in Magento's default theme for onepagecheckout - upon load it calls `payment.init()` which is an object literal function:

```
init : function () {
    var elements = Form.getElements(this.form);
    var method = null;
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].name=='payment[method]') {
            if (elements[i].checked) {
                method = elements[i].value;
            }
        } else {
            elements[i].disabled = true;
        }
    }
    if (method) this.switchMethod(method);
},
```

For some reason, in IE9 only, it seems that the input boxes in the payment form default to "disabled=true"... is there a better way to accomplish this?  IE9 is the only one that misbehaves here...

**Update:**

My temporary fix has been to disable this call altogether. We do not require hidden fields to be disabled. Is this a requirement to maintain compatibility?

Comment: It should be known that the `disabled=true` and `disabled=false` and `disabled=i'm hungry` should all disable the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be related to incompatibility between older Prototype library used by Magento and IE9. More information available here: http://alanstorm.com/ie9_fix_for_magento 
Note that upgrade of Prototype library is planned for next releases.

Comment: Maybe this  will helpfull - http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/158644/9951